# Gridview not filling parent in custom preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm using a custom preference to display a gridview. But this gridview is not filling up the parent space.

[image]

Here is my pref_background.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <com.test.package.ImageChooserPreference
        android:key="background" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And here is my gallery_preference.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0" >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my gallery_item_row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/gallery_color_selector"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/checked"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/checked"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I do to fill space with `com.test.package.ImageChooserPreference`?

Comment: Please add your row item layout

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. Just added it

Comment: Increase width and height of image

Comment: But I don't want bigger image. This size of image is great for me. I just want the GridView to fill up parent space.

Comment: @guillaume I think your gridview now is fill up parent. can you explain more

Comment: On the screenshot the GridView is stacked on top. And I would like the GridView to expand to fit parent. The GridView contains several line of items and I have to scroll on the small part on top to view all items.

Comment: I have edited the screenshot

Comment: your gridview don't have enough item so it will not fill the height of parent
could you set the background color for gridview then update your screenshot?

Comment: I have updated screenshot, there is enough item (you can see the scrollbar).
But according to the separator under the GridView, it seems the space problem is related to com.test.package.ImageChooserPreference which is an extended class of PreferenceFragment.

Comment: Is it due to PreferenceScreen lack of customization?